# Implementation of CI/CD Flow with Gradle, Jenkins, and Sonar

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, sonarqube

So, I am currently attempting to implement a CI/CD workflow for a project of mine that will be released to the public. Because what I'm releasing is more of a framework, I acknowledge that people will take my code, change it how they see fit, and host their changes themselves (if they want). So I do not want to impose anything **extra** on their build process (ie. checkstyle rules, unnecessary dependencies, etc).

So that path I (personally) have opted for to write the framework is to use Gradle for building, and on commit, kick off a Jenkins build, which will run all unit tests, perform static analysis, and then package the necessary files into a format people can download.

1. Write Code
2. Run Local Unit Tests
3. Commit Code
4. Kick off Jenkins Build
5. Run Unit Tests
6. Run Integration Tests
7. Perform analysis on result
8. Upload analysis to SonarQube server
9. Take build files and package into binary, and source releases.

My problem however is that I am unable to configure the Sonar aspect of it all in Jenkins. As I said, I don't want to impose my rules on someone else's process, so I separated the functionality as a Jenkins step. However, if I execute the Sonar step, it will completely exclude the unit test aspect. I am unable to determine the cause. However, if I modify the Gradle file to include

```
apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'
```

and add an `Invoke Gradle Task` step instead of a Sonar task, it work fine.

Am I going about this the wrong way? If I include that part in the Gradle file, I get what I need out of it, but I'm imposing the Gradle requirement on whoever downloads my code (perhaps that use Maven instead). Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't "imposing" anything by including the sonar plugin in your Gradle build script. A developer isn't required to run the sonar tasks to build your project, and so long as any necessary configuration required for configuring sonar doesn't break the build if it is missing, I'd say you are good to go.

It is not uncommon for open source project builds to contain logic specific to release or deployment. This is fine so long as a) running these tasks outside of the designated CI environment fails (typically due to lack of permission to upload to release repo) and b) developers can still build/test without needing to run those tasks.

In general, I think your latter approach is better, since you now have less of a dependency on a particular CI infrastructure, which would make migration easier.